# How to open XHTTP Request in new browser window

Tags: javascript, typescript, xmlhttprequest

I have a requirement to open the url in new window, but it needs to pass the parameters in headers, so i am thinking of preparing a xhttprequest with header and open it in new window.
Is it feasible to open xhttprequest in new window ? Can anyone help.